# Batch empty subfolders from folders in a CSV file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a very long list of partail names for folders (each partial is unique to a specific folder); what I am looking to do is write a batch file to go through each of the sub-folders within each folder, pull the files to the root of that folder, and replace the files if there's duplication (there is a lot of duplication we're looking to remove).

I've used a couple batch files to move and do other things with these folders, I just can't get the code to work on emptying subfolders.

Batch file 1 (accessing CSV, calling the other batch to do the work):

```csh
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%G IN (Pt1Test.csv) DO call Empty1.bat %%G
```

Batch file 2 (is supposed to empty the subfolders, then move along to the next folder in the list):

```csh
@echo off
set _Uname=%1
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b^|find "%_Uname%"') do <NEXT BIT I CAN'T FIGURE OUT>
```

The problem I'm having is getting the command to pull *within* the main folder.

I know this code works when I throw it right into DOS:

```csh
for /r %f in (*) do @move /y "%f"
```

But I can't have a for, do, for, do and I don't want to have to type that in for the 5000 or so folders I'd like to remove duplication from.

Thanks for any help!

Tyler

Comment: `and replace the files if there's overlap` <-- what does that mean?

Comment: Edited to clarify that.  I meant to say replace files if there is duplication (overwrite), the /y in the @move command does this.

Comment: Are the files binary duplicates and you want to remove all except one copy?  Is this the main aim of the exercise?  Or do they have the same filename and you want to keep only one copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason for the 1,3? You aren't using the 3 (%%H) in your examples.

How about this? Just change to each directory and back, before your 2nd command.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,3 delims=," %%G IN (Pt1Test.csv) DO (
    pushd *%%G*
    for /r %%a in (*) do @move /y "%%a" 
    popd
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!  I don't need 1,3, just 1, forgot to change that from an earlier script.